# Where can I find the correct config for my organization for use with sfdx?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx-cli

I am new at my organization. I'd like to download all the Apex classes. I am on a Mac and I am working directly in the Terminal. (I might setup VSCode later, but for now I'm just working in the Terminal.)

I start by getting authorized:

```
sfdx auth:device:login -r https://fakename.my.salesforce.com
```

That went well.

I tried:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass
```

but I got an error message about not having my local folder setup correctly. I needed to create this file:

```
sfdx-project.json
```

Okay, no problem, I create the problem. I look up a generic example online and I copy-and-paste this:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "56.0"
}
```

The only thing I change is `sourceApiVersion`.

Now I can run:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass
```

that sort of works but it only downloads two folders with config files:

```
.sf
.sfdx
```

I know that we have hundreds of Apex classes, but none of them download.

I'm thinking maybe the problem is that I don't have the correct metadata in `sfdx-project.json`? How would I find such information? Or is the problem something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the folder be set up correctly, consider just moving to the parent folder and creating a project:

```
sfdx force project create -n myExistingFolderName
```

It'll create all the necessary files and folders you need to get started for real.

Next, move into that directory and set the default user:

```
cd myExistingFolderName
sfdx force config set defaultusername=my-username-or-alias
```

And also, use npm to install any dependencies you might need:

```
npm i
```

Now, you should be able to get your metadata:

```
sfdx force source retrieve -m ApexClass
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I've been trying to set this up for weeks and I could not find these exact instructions anywhere! Salesforce needs to take what you wrote here and add it to their setup instructions, especially for anyone with a Mac!